# Printing specific lines txt file python

Tags: python

I have a text file I wish to analyze. I'm trying to find every line that contains certain characters (ex: "@") and then print the line located 3 lines before it (ex: if line 5 contains "@", I would like to print line 2)
This is what I got so far:

```
file = open('new_file.txt', 'r')    
a = list()
x = 0
for line in file:
    x = x + 1
    if '@' in line:
        a.append(x)
        continue
    x = 0   
for index, item in enumerate(a):
        for line in file:
            x = x + 1
            d = a[index]
            if x == d - 3:
                print line
                continue
```

It won't work (it prints nothing when I feed it a file that has lines containing "@"), any ideas?

Comment: Your program is not syntactically correct (issues in intentation). Can you please fix that first, please. Next, can you please specify "won't work". (And of course you should get rid of the "nested" reading of the same file descriptor...)

Answer (score 0):

First, you are going through the file multiple times without re-opening it for subsequent times. That means all subsequent attempts to iterate the file will terminate immediately without reading anything.

Second, your indexing logic a little convoluted. Assuming your files are not huge relative to your memory size, it is much easier to simply read the whole into memory (as a list) and manipulate it there.

```
myfile = open('new_file.txt', 'r')    
a = myfile.readlines();
for index, item in enumerate(a):
    if '@' in item and index - 3 >= 0:
       print a[index - 3].strip()
```

This has been tested on the following input:

```
PrintMe
PrintMe As Well
Foo
@Foo
Bar@
hello world will print
null
null
@@
```

Answer (score -1):

For file IO it is usually most efficient for programmer time and runtime to use reg-ex to match patterns. In combination with iteration through the lines in the file. your problem really isn't a problem.

```
import re
file = open('new_file.txt', 'r')
document = file.read()
lines = document.split("\n")
LinesOfInterest = []
for lineNumber,line in enumerate(lines):
    WhereItsAt = re.search( r'@', line)
    if(lineNumber>2 and WhereItsAt):
        LinesOfInterest.append(lineNumber-3)
print LinesOfInterest
for lineNumber in LinesOfInterest:
    print(lines[lineNumber])
```

Lines of Interest is now a list of line numbers matching your criteria

I used

```
line1,0
line2,0
line3,0
@
line1,1
line2,1
line3,1
@
line1,2
line2,2
line3,2
@
line1,3
line2,3
line3,3
@
```

as input yielding

```
[0, 4, 8, 12]
line1,0
line1,1
line1,2
line1,3
```

Comment: amazing! what if I were to match more than "@", example the line should contain any (not necessarily all) of the following ("mail","@", "user")

Comment: WhereItsAt = re.search( r'@|mail|user', line)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the issue is that you have already iterated completely through the file descriptor `file` in line 4 when you try again in line 11. So line 11 will make an empty loop. Maybe it would be a better idea to iterate the file only once and remember the last few lines...

```
file = open('new_file.txt', 'r')
a = ["","",""]
for line in file:
    if "@" in line:
        print(a[0], end="")
    a.append(line)
    a = a[1:]
```